# How can i set a default value of input with React hook form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```
const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
```

```
<input {...register("title")} type="text" value="I want a default value" />
```

When input is rendered in DOM i want it to have a default value saying `I want a default value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/):

```
useForm({
  mode: 'onSubmit',
  reValidateMode: 'onChange',
  defaultValues: {},
  resolver: undefined,
  context: undefined,
  criteriaMode: "firstError",
  shouldFocusError: true,
  shouldUnregister: false,
  shouldUseNativeValidation: false,
  delayError: undefined
})
```

In your code it would work like this:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    title: 'I want a default value'
  }
});
```

```
<input {...register("title")} type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
const defaultValue = {
 text: "I want a default value."
};

<input
        {...register("title")} type=text
        defaultValue={defaultValue.text}
      />
```